# Nested Arrays in Javascript have weird, undefined behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, nested

When I make a nested array in Javascript using this:

```
let arr = Array(5).fill(Array(5).fill("O"))
```

It properly shows a 5x5 array of "O"

However, when I do:

```
arr[1][0] = "S"
```

It shows a result of:

```
["S", "O", "O", "O", "O"],
["S", "O", "O", "O", "O"],
["S", "O", "O", "O", "O"],
["S", "O", "O", "O", "O"],
["S", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
```

instead of just overwriting a single O.

Comment: Each row must be a reference to the same array.

Comment: `.fill` takes a single *value*, it doesn't call the methods over and over again.

Comment: *"Nested Arrays in Javascript have weird, undefined behavior"* **Nothing** in JavaScript has undefined behavior. *Weird* sometimes, yes, but never *undefined*. :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`Array.fill` returns the array, so the same array reference exists on each "row".